# sublime: bind "git: add…" from command palette to hotkey

Tags: git, sublimetext2, key-bindings, sublimetext, git-add

I'd like to bind action "Git: add…" (multiple files selection) from sublime command palette.

`command: show_overlay {"overlay": "command_palette"} //shows command palette itself`

command: git_add_choice //shows git:add… list

Binding this commands like that - fails

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+q"], "command": "git_add_choice"}`

{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+q"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "git_add_choice"} }

Comment: problem only with lists, single command like this { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+q"], "command": "git_quick_commit" } works perfect

Answer (score 0):

[The Sublime Docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html#id3)(see show_overlay section) seem to say that the allowed values for "overlay" are only "goto" and "command_palette."  I looked through the keybindings defined in my installed packages, and these were the only overlays used.